# How can I include SWF Animations in a document?

Tags: xetex, animations, media9, swf

Minimal tex

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{media9}

\begin{document}
\includemedia[
  activate=pageopen,
  width=200pt,
  height=150pt
]{}{Heartaxis.swf}
\end{document}
```

Everything runs fine in XeLaTeX typesetting engine apparently with the above code, but I see the [animation](http://en.ecgpedia.org/wiki/QRS_axis) as

[image]

I have previewed the result now in many viewers with same view.
The background should be white, not dark grey.

**How can you include SWF file in pdf?**

Probably, some other file format than PDF has better support for SWF. 
PS or other?

Comment: My first thought is to read http://tug.org/pracjourn/2010-1/scarso/scarso.pdf.

Comment: Your code works fine for me and opening with Adobe Reader I'm able to see the video in the PDF.

Comment: @Malipivo: too much to be read ;). Just use `media9`.

Comment: Masi, in the future, could you please, whenever applicable, title your TeX.SE questions by an actual question instead of "To <do-this-or-that>"? That would make the topic of your posts less ambiguous.

Comment: One word: Don't

Comment: @morbusg: Plz explain w hy?

Comment: @AlexG: wrong media; use HTML

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update**

This issue is related to SWFs with transparent background (the main SWF Application widget doesn't provide an own background colour). `media9` has recently been fixed to cope with such SWF files.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{media9}[2014/08/06]

\begin{document}
\includemedia[
  activate=pageopen,
  width=200pt,
  height=150pt
]{}{http://nl.ecgpedia.org/images/c/cc/Heartaxis.swf}
\end{document}
```