# How can you label an included pdfdocument and refer to it?

Tags: pdf, pdfpages

I have

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}   
Lorem. Read the answer for this from the document \ref{3rd_part}
....

\appendix
\includepdf[pages={-}]{3rd_part.pdf} \label{3rd_part} % NOT working, problem here!
\end{document}
```

This labelling does not work.

There is no need for

- no figure environment
- no table environment
- no caption,

since the document is only a WYSIWYG made document.

**How can you label an included pdfdocument and refer to it?**

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/166875/how-can-i-include-swf-animations-in-a-document#comment383531_166875

Comment: Seems to be very complicated solution there. I just want to refer to the included document, not to a particular page.

Comment: Since what you are refering to is an Appendix, you should instead start an appendinx chapter and then refer to that chapter.  It is by far more elegant, structured and simpler

Comment: The problem is: What is contained in your pdf page? Is it text, graphics, tables, all of it? Do you need a `figure` or `table` environment? Should it have a caption? Shall there be an entry to some `list of anything`?

Comment: @MarioS.E. If the pdf page is just the first content of the `appendix section`, this is a quick solution, but not, if the page is to be shifted to some later place. Especially if `hyperref` is used, the link would go to some other place, i.e. right to the start of the appendix section

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I need no figure or table environment. No caption.  It is only a WYSIWYG made document.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer no no, I mean, after the `\appendix` command start a chapter where the pdf is `\includepdf`.  This would allow to actually name the Appendix, e.g. "Math demonstration" and also would allow to `\ref` it later, since you are pointing to the beginning of the chapter

Comment: @MarioS.E. Now I got you, of course, you need a counter which can be `refstepped` and then use `label` on it

Comment: @Masi: I refer to Mario S.E. proposition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about something like this?

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}   
Lorem. Read the answer for this from the document located in Appendix~\ref{3rdpart}

\appendix
\chapter{Appendix Name}\label{3rdpart}
\includepdf[pages={-}]{uporto-feup.pdf}  % Your pdf file here instead of uporto-feup.pdf

\end{document}
```

Since you seem to be using `\appendix`, you can start it by a chapter ---which would be not numbered, but in letter sequence (A, B, C, et.c) and you can refer to it back from your document.

Like this:

[image]

And then you'll have at your appendix something like this:

[image]

My `\includedpdf` is the figure you see, the logo of the University of Porto